# ENOTFOUND error keeps occurring in docker and sequelize

Tags: docker, express, sequelize.js

First of all, I tried my best through other stackoverflow posts and Googling, but the same error keeps occurring.

```
docker run --rm  --name mysql-container -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d -p 3305:3306 mysql:latest
```

First, if I run the mysql container with the above command, it runs normally.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                   CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                               NAMES
5980ecc42a28   mysql:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   36 seconds ago   Up 35 seconds   33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3305->3306/tcp   mysql-container
```

- Dockerfile

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install 

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

After that, if I create a Dockerfile like this and build it, it builds normally.

```
docker build -t goals-node .
```

After that, when I try to run the image I built, the 'ENOTFOUND' error continues to occur.

### - app.js

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const express = require("express");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config({ path: "./env/mysql.env" });

const Goal = require("./models/goal");

const app = express();

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
  process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  process.env.MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD,
  {
    port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT,
    host: "mysql",
    dialect: "mysql",
    logging: false,
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000,
    },
  }
);
```

### - env/mysql.env

```
MYSQL_DATABASE=docker_test
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=itspassword // its not real password
MYSQL_PASSWORD=itspassword
MYSQL_DATA_DIR=./mysql_data
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PORT=3305
```

### - error

```
myComputer@myComputer-MacBookPro backend % docker run --name goals-backend --rm  goals-node
80 port is ready
HostNotFoundError [SequelizeHostNotFoundError]: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mysql
    at ConnectionManager.connect (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:96:17)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ConnectionManager._connect (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:222:24)
    at async /app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:174:32
    at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:197:7)
    at async /app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:305:26
    at async Sequelize.authenticate (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:457:5)
  parent: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mysql
      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (node:dns:118:26) {
    errno: -3008,
    code: 'ENOTFOUND',
    syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
    hostname: 'mysql',
    fatal: true
  },
  original: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mysql
      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (node:dns:118:26) {
    errno: -3008,
    code: 'ENOTFOUND',
    syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
    hostname: 'mysql',
    fatal: true
  }
}
```

- package.json

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "errorTest",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql2": "^3.7.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.35.2",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.6.2"
  }
}
```

### - goal.js

```js
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

module.exports = class Goal extends Sequelize.Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    return super.init(
      {
        text: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
        },
      },
      {
        sequelize,
        modelName: "Goals",
        tableName: "goals",
      }
    );
  }
  static associate(db) {}
};
```

I looked through other articles and changed the settings for equalization in app.js, but the same error continues to occur. What's the problem?

please help...

I've tried Googling and searching gpt, but the same problem occurs.

Comment: You have not included the content of your `package.json`, so it's not possible to completely replicate your setup. Could you please add that to your original question too? 

Comment: Also you have not included your local package `./models/goal`. It's probably not relevant to the problem, but would be required to run your code as provided. I'm going to just comment out that line in the script. 

Comment: When you launch the MySQL container you're specifying a password of "password", but in `env/mysql.env` the password is "itspassword". Perhaps these should be consistent?

Comment: I left everything I needed. I would really appreciate it if you could check it out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason that you're getting the `ENOTFOUND` error is that your two Docker containers are effectively sitting on different networks.

The quickest (but not best) way to get this simply working would be to launch them both using the host's network. The setup below should get everything **working**, which is always a good place to start. You can then tweak bits and pieces until it all does what you need.

Launch your database like this:

```bash
docker run --rm --name mysql-container \
  --net=host \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password \
  -d \
  mysql:latest
```

That will launch the MySQL container. Since it's on the host network the database will be accessible on port 3306.

Update the environment file:

```
MYSQL_DATABASE=mysql
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
MYSQL_DATA_DIR=./mysql_data
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PORT=3306
```

We're using the (default) `mysql` database. When you create another database on the server you can specify that here. Have also changed the port to 3306.

Here's the updated app:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const express = require("express");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config({ path: "./env/mysql.env" });

// const Goal = require("./models/goal");

const app = express();

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
  process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  process.env.MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD,
  {
    port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT,
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    dialect: "mysql",
    logging: false,
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000,
    },
  }
);
sequelize.authenticate();
```

I've updated the `host` to `"127.0.0.1"` so that it connects to localhost (which is what we want because we're using host networking).

I added a `package.json` with the required packages.

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
          "dotenv": "*",
          "express": "*",
          "morgan": "*",
          "mysql2": "*",
          "sequelize": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  },
  "main": "n/a",
  "scripts": {
  }
}
```

The build and run.

```bash
docker build -t goals-node . 
docker run --net=host --name goals-backend --rm  goals-node
```

This container is also run using host networking, so it's able to connect to the MySQL container.

If you want to create a new database (that is, not use the default database) then you'd need to specify the name of the database when you launch the MySQL container and update the environment file.

```bash
docker run --rm --name mysql-container \
  --net=host \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password \
  -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test \
  -d \
  mysql:latest
```

```
MYSQL_DATABASE=test
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
MYSQL_DATA_DIR=./mysql_data
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PORT=3306
```

Once you have this working I'd suggest that your next step would be to use Docker Compose. This is a more robust way to handle communication between multiple containers.

Hope this helps. Feel free to post comments or questions and I'll update accordingly.

Comment: thank you It works fine!

however,
If I set the value of MYSQL_DATABASE=mysql to mysql, it works normally, but if I set it to a different value such as mysql_test,
80 port is ready
ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: Unknown database 'mysql_test'
    at ConnectionManager.connect (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:102:17)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

This error occurs.

Do I have to write the table name in mysql?

Comment: And the original package.json is
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "test,
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.2",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql2": "^3.7.1",
    "sequelize": "^6.35.2",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.6.2"
  }
}
It was set up like this, do I need to add private as true?

Comment: I have added an explanation of how you can change the name of the database at the end of my answer.

Comment: No, you don't need to include `"private"`. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using plain Docker and not Compose, there are three things you need to do to make the containers connect to each other.

The first is to create a Docker network.  For historical reasons, plain `docker run` uses a legacy networking mode where containers can't reach each other without special setup.  You do not need any non-default options, you just need to create the network with some name.

```bash
docker network create some-network
```

When you run the two containers, you need to run them both on the same network.

```bash
docker run -d \
  --name mysql-container \
  --net some-network \     # <--
  ...
  mysql:latest
docker run -d \
  --name goals \
  --net some-network \     # <--
  ...
  goals-node
```

Finally, when you make the connection between containers, use the server's container name as a host name.  I'd recommend making the database host name configurable the same way the other settings are.

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  ...,
  {
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    ...
  }
);
```

```bash
MYSQL_HOST=mysql-container
MYSQL_PORT=3306
```

You use a `docker run -p 3305:3306` option to remap the database port to a different host port.  Connections between containers don't use (or require) these mappings, so I've also changed `MYSQL_PORT` back to the default MySQL port 3306.  If you're not going to access the database from outside this container (including using things like the `mysql` CLI from the host) then it's safe to delete the `-p` option entirely.